# Android - Added image in html webview but image doesn't show

Tags: java, android, html

My Code:

```
 web.loadData("<html><body> " + result.getHtmltext().replaceAll("<span class=\"stl_23 stl_10\" style=\"word-spacing:0em;\">-------------------------------</span>",
                        "<img height=\" 500\" width=\"500\" src=" + " \" " + "file:///android_asset/logo_transparent.png" + "\" " + "/>") + "</body></html>", "text/html; charset=UTF-8", null);
```

But doesn't work:
[image]

Comment: have u already added image to asset folder?

Comment: @ZarNiMyoSettWin yes

Comment: @Dahlia are you loading html from assets folder

Comment: @RahulKhurana Nope. It's html from server.

Comment: @Dahlia see my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can give it a try

```
String htmlData = "<body>" + "<img src=\"logo_transparent.png\"/></body>";
webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("file:///android_asset/",htmlData , "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

with this, it will start picking up images from the assets folder directly.

Comment: OMG. You're the best. Thank you so much <3